# Flutter: How to make a PopupMenu with color gradient?

Tags: flutter, gradient, popupmenu

i'm try to create a PopupMenu with background is color gradient by the way create a class extend PopupMenuEntry. but it have some space i dont know how to remove it

this is my code:

```
class PopupMenuWidget<T> extends PopupMenuEntry<T> {
  const PopupMenuWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.height = 30,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  final Widget child;

  @override
  final double height;

  @override
  bool get enabled => false;

  @override
  _PopupMenuWidgetState createState() => _PopupMenuWidgetState();

  @override
  bool represents(T? value) {
    return true;
  }
}

class _PopupMenuWidgetState extends State<PopupMenuWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xff358BAC),
                Color(0xff261C70),
              ]),
        ),
        child: widget.child,
      );
}
```

i'm also create a method build action and call it in `action` of appbar.

```
 Widget buildAction() {
    return PopupMenuButton<int>(
      itemBuilder: (context) {
        return [
          PopupMenuWidget(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Get The App",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        // sized box with width 10
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.white),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(color: Colors.white),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 1,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Get The App",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        // sized box with width 10
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.white),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      icon: Image.asset(
        Assets.icDot,
        color: Colors.white,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
      ),
      // offset: Offset(0, 100),
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 2,
      position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
      onSelected: (int value) {
        print("You selected $value");
      },
    );
  }
```

and this is UI now

[i want to remove white color, but i dont know how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyBG2.png)

Comment: wherever you are using PopupMenuWidget, wrap that into a container and give that container a color or make it transparent like color: Colors.white.withOpacity(your_variable_value)

Comment: can't wrap that into container because it's a child of popupMenuButton

Comment: popupMenuButton has property ```itemBuilder``` and it ```{required List<PopupMenuEntry<int>> Function(BuildContext) itemBuilder}```

Comment: you need to wrap with container as parent widget of popupMenuButton.

Comment: still not working :((. if i warp container as parent of popUpMenuButton. it's just change color of button. not change color of pop up menu